# maven project with netbeans compiles fully on every run

Tags: ide, netbeans, maven

I was experimenting with Netbeans 6.8 (I'm currently an Eclipse user) because I like having a profiler built into the IDE. It seems that for maven projects, netbeans does a full compile (it invokes process-classes) every time I try to run the project, as opposed to Eclipse, which uses the incremental Java compiler. Is there a way to avoid having netbeans run `mvn process-classes` every time I want to run the main class?

thanks,
Jeff

Comment: Are you sure? There is nothing bound to `process-classes` by default (this phase is typically used for bytecode post-processing). Or could this be due to the profiling?

Comment: I did profile once, and that caused it, which makes sense since the code needs to be instrumented. I do have groovy code in my project. Could it have something to do with the joint java/groovy compiling?

Answer (score 0):

As I wrote in a comment to the question, there is nothing bound to `process-classes` by default so the question is: what is currently occurring during this phase?

It could be indeed something related to profiling (to instrument the code). In that case, see if deactivating the profiling solves the problem.

It could also be somehow related to the Groovy support. I can't test this right now but when I look at [this thread](http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic12470.html), I see that the exec-maven-plugin is called during `process-classes`. But I have no idea if this is done by NetBeans or if the POM contains stuff causing this (and the thread is almost one year old so things might have changed).

Could you post Maven's output?

Comment: It looks like the issue was I had snapshots being pulled always, which resulted in a rebuild (I think that's the case). Though it's still not playing completely nice with groovy, the stubs for groovy files from src/test seem to be empty files, which is weird - I'm not sure if it's all of them or just some of them. But that's a new problem now.

Comment: Note: It looks like the netbeans IDE is just not refreshing those stubbed files. In windows explorer, they are full files, but the IDE shows them as unparseable, blank files.

Comment: this second issue has been opened as a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696121/netbeans-6-8-groovy-files-in-src-main-java
Thanks.